# How to align two buttons horizontally

Tags: html, css

How do I make two button aligned horizontally in a div? I want no space between the two buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, they are by default aligned. Just check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SdhQw/) code snippet and you'll understand better :) Just make sure to leave no white space between the buttons.

Comment: Thanks. I was using <button> tag, they are not aligned horizontally by default.

Answer (score 2):

Float the buttons and add `overflow: hidden` to your container : http://jsfiddle.net/SdhQw/

Comment: This is what did it for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could float them.

```
div button {
   float: left;
   margin: 0;
}
```